# How can i handle python code with tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

intNum1 = int(input("enter num 1: "))
intNum2 = int(input("enter num 2: "))

num1 = tf.Variable(intNum1)
num2 = tf.Variable(intNum2)

sum = tf.add(num1, num2)

print("sum = " + str(sum))

globalVarsInitializer = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  globalVarsInitializer.run()
  result = sum.eval()

print("result = " + str(result))
```

I installed tensorflow 2 successfully but when i run python code i see this lines and my code not workning

[image]

Comment: I would recommended verifying that tensorflow is installed in the python environment that you are using for this code using sys or if you are using conda, check with conda list

Answer (score -1):

You have some problems with CUDA and/or CuDNN dependencies. Ensure that you're following [GPU installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).